# Uneven Grid Spacing of 3D splot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have 3D data in a tab-delimited text file of form x,y,z. One dimension is equispaced, while the other has denser points near zero and they get sparse as you go further out. e.g.

```
178   200    .023...
178   198    .024...
........................
178  -200    .023...
156   200    .023...
```

I would like to do a surface plot in gnuplot where the grid lines on the surface represent this non-uniform nature. Every time I use dgrid3d, it adjusts everything to a uniform grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `dgrid3d` is to put your data on a regular grid, so you should not use that. Just use a regular `splot` command, keeping in mind that your data should contain an empty line after each row. For example, if `test.dat` is

```
1       1       2
1       2       3
1       5       6

2       1       3
2       2       4
2       5       7

5       1       6
5       2       7
5       5       10
```

then

```
splot "test.dat" w lp
```

will result in

[image]